# how to AWS lambda trigger mail using yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-sqs

Trigger message when filter criteria matches,in yaml file.

This code is triggering message to sqs queue, and shows message available also,but at endpoint message is not delivered to user emailid.

policies:
  - name: high-risk-groups
    resource: security-group
    description: |
      Remove any rule from a security group that allows open ports ingress
      and notify the user who added the violating rule.
    filters:
     - type: ingress
       Cidr:
        value_type: cidr
        op: eq
        value: "0.0.0.0/0"
    mode:
       role: arn:aws:iam::91*******:role/rolename
       schedule: 'cron(30/10 10 * * ? *)'
       type: periodic

```
actions:
 - type: notify
   template: default.html
   priority_header: 1
   subject: "Open Security Group Rule Created-[ {{ account }} - {{ region }}]"
   violation_desc: |
     "Security Group(s) Which Had Rules Open To The World:"
   action_desc: |
     "Actions taken"
     "Actions Taken: The Violating Security Group Rule Needs to be Removed As It
     Violates Our Company's Cloud Policy. Please Refer To The Cloud FAQ."
   to:
     - user@gmail.com
   transport:
     type: sqs
     queue: https://sqs.region-id.amazonaws.com/91*******/queuename
     region: eu-west-1
```

Message is passing to queue but it is not delivered to usermail. can we trigger mails with SQS rather than using SES/SNS?

Comment: Is this for a specific tool, such as CloudCustodian? https://github.com/cloud-custodian/cloud-custodian

Comment: yes this is for cloudCustodian,can we trigger mails using SQS?As this code is executing properly message available in queue.But It is not sent to specific userid mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything in the [official documentation](https://cloudcustodian.io/docs/aws/resources/aws-common-actions.html#aws-common-actions-notify) for this, but my theory is you can't mix the `to` field with the `sqs` transport type.

`actions` is a list, so you should probably have two actions: one with the email address and `sns` transport type (as the example in the documentation), and another using just the `sqs` transport type.